What is a fast way to count how many times a given value is present in an ArrayList?
ArrayList<Integer> myArrayList = new ArrayList<>;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    myArrayList.add(i);
}
myArrayList.add(2);
myArrayList.add(2);
myArrayList.add(3);

//arryaylist contains: (0,1,2,3,4,2,2,3)

I want to give input to a method, and for it to return amount of times the input is seen in the array. For example:
public int someMethod(int searchVal) {
    //code
    //returns int
}
    
System.out.println(someMethod(2));
//prints 3

I can think of a way like:
public int someMethod(int searchVal) {
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i : myArraylist) {
        if (i == searchVal) {
            counter +=1;
        } 
    }
    return counter; 
}

But the arraylist I need this method for is very long and I'm going to use it multiple times for each of the possible values in the ArrayList. Meaning i.e. someMethod(0), someMethod(1), someMethod(2), someMethod(3), someMethod(4).
In the example I have int, but I will use ArrayList. In form of: ArrayList<ArrayList< Integer >> myArrayList = ((1,2) , (2,1), (1,2), (3,0)...) So .sort() will not work.

Is there a faster way to generally calculate how many times an individual value is present in an ArrayList?
Since I'm going to use this on all values, is there a faster way of doing this than having method that compares each value?


Premature optimization is the root of all evil

The wombat is correct, but also perhaps a list is the wrong data structure.  Consider a tree or a hash map for faster access times.

Is the ArrayList fixed, i.e. does it always contain the same elements? Or will you be adding or removing or modifying values in the ArrayList between invocations of method someMethod? Your answers will help determine whether ArrayList is the most suitable data structure - as indicated by @markspace in his comment.

From the way you can think of, don’t use == for comparing objects (elements in an ArrayList are always objects). Please see Why is 128==128 false but 127==127 is true when comparing Integer wrappers in Java?

There is no faster way for the computer than running linearly through the list and counting. There are faster ways of typing it than what you have done, and probably also code that is faster to read and understand (which is what matters, really).

You can get your frequency table with Map<Integer, Long> counts = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(val->val, Collectors.counting())); Look up the value(s) of interest with counts.get(...)

As you say you're going to use ArrayList<ArrayList< Integer >>, is your counting method also going to be someMethod(ArrayList< Integer >) or will it remain someMethod(int)? In other words, are you trying to count elements in a 2-dimensional list? Or counting how many lists in the given list-of-lists are identical to the passed list?

The ArrayList has different values inside it. I will store and remove coordinates from it. Once a coordinate pair is in, it will not be changed, only removed. Duplicates of coordinates can exist and in practicality that's what I will be counting with someMethod, the amount of duplicate coordinates of a specific coordinate pair. someMethod will be called multiple times and adding or removing can happen between those calls.

Your data seem to be modeled incorrectly. If you have coordinates, you should have a collection of tuple/point objects

To count the occurrences of all list values, you can use a stream with Collectors.groupingBy and Collectors.counting
myArrayList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));

This groups the values of the list by their identity, and then for each group, counts how many elements are in the group, returning a map with the list values as the keys, and the occurrence counts as the values.
In your example:
var myArrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    myArrayList.add(i);
}
myArrayList.add(2);
myArrayList.add(2);
myArrayList.add(3);

Map<Integer, Long> counts =
        myArrayList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
System.out.println(counts);

Output:
{0=1, 1=1, 2=3, 3=2, 4=1}


parallelStream() ! This is one of those extremely rare cases, where automatic  arary splitting and Collectors reduce should actually be quicker than serial processing.

@Basilevs Probably only for huge amounts of items though.

As OP specified

@Basilevs Then they will need to measure it. The thing with parallel-streams is that the setup cost usually dwarfs the actual computational cost, and especially when talking about counting and grouping things, the computational cost is almost negligible (and "very long" is in the eye of the beholder).

In my case (2. section) it was better change the datatype to hashmap<ArrayList<Integer>, Integer>
Originally I had a lot of coordinates and I needed to know how many times each coordinate was present in the list. Different coordinates could be added and removed, but in the end I just needed to know the amount and corresponding coordinate.
Now I changed the list into a hashmap of coordinates whose values were the amount of times that coordinate was present. This made the code much cleaner and still relatively fast.
Thanks for all the responses and help.

I probably could change the ArrayList into just Array since I won't be changing the values of stored coordinates.

I understand, from your answer, that your question is no longer relevant since you changed the data structure from List to Map. Therefore I think that you should consider deleting your question - unless you believe that it (and its answers) will help others.
